# Mouse trigger not properly happening if html created through JQuery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, triggers, mouse

> **HTML**

```
<div id="header">top of page</div>
<div class="message">hello, how are you</div>
<div class="message">I am fine</div>
```

> **jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#header").append('<div class="message">appended DIV</div>');
    $('div.message').hover(
        function () {
            alert('hi');
        },
        function () {
            alert('bye');
        }
    );
});
```

Why do the existing DIVs in the HTML trigger the mouse even and hence alert, but the appended DIV will not and is 'dead.' How can the appended DIV react like the existing ones?

> **edit: in summary this was the solution:**

```
$('<span />').addClass('message').text('(mouse 1)').appendTo('#header');
$('<span />').addClass('message').text('(mouse 2)').appendTo('#header');

$('.message').hover(
    function () {
        $('#header').prepend('in');
    },
    function () {
        $('#header').prepend('out');
    }
);
```

**Note, if the SPANs are placed below the hover function, it won't work.**

Comment: Works fine for me...  which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chome and FF3 - see here: http://jobs.happyzion.com/test.html

Comment: on that test page, if you put your mouse over "put mouse here" (answer) or "added message here" (question example) I cannot see any message alert. I'm sorry, but I cannot accept a correct answer.

Comment: I've tried IE, Seamonkey, Opera too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the resulting generated XHTML from your current code:

```
<div id="header2">put mouse here<div class="message"></div></div>
```

As you can see, the part you expect to hover over has no text.

Try:

```
$('<div />').addClass('message').text('appended DIV').appendTo('#header');
```

You will now see the text inside a new `div` with the `message` class attached.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because this way you are appending text and not creating a DOM object, which you can later select.

You should probably do something like:

```
var divObj = $('<div>').attr('class', 'message');
$('#header').append(divObj);
$(divObj).hover(
    function () {
        alert('hi');
    },
    function () {
        alert('bye');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works perfectly for me in Firefox, so I think it must be something else that's the problem. Anything else you think could be affecting it?